# OpenLayers 2 to highlight city

Tags: openlayers-2

This is the code to highlight and pop up a country area on mouse click:

```
window.onload = function () {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {sphericalMercator: true});
    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM({sphericalMercator: true});

    var shpLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector({projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326')});
    map.addLayers([osm, shpLayer]);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 1);

    // Interaction; not needed for initial display.
    selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(shpLayer);
    map.addControl(selectControl);
    selectControl.activate();
    shpLayer.events.on({
        'featureselected': onFeatureSelect,
        'featureunselected': onFeatureUnselect
    });

    // load the shapefile
    var theUrl = 'naturalearthdata/cultural/110m-admin-0-countries';
    getOpenLayersFeatures(theUrl, function (fs) {
    // reproject features
    // this is ordinarily done by the format object, but since we're adding features manually we have to do it.
    var fsLen = fs.length;
    var inProj = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
    var outProj = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3857');
    for (var i = 0; i < fsLen; i++) {
        fs[i].geometry = fs[i].geometry.transform(inProj, outProj);
    }
    shpLayer.addFeatures(fs);
    });
}


    // Needed only for interaction, not for the display.
    function onPopupClose(evt) {
        // 'this' is the popup.
        var feature = this.feature;
        if (feature.layer) { // The feature is not destroyed
        selectControl.unselect(feature);
        } else { // After "moveend" or "refresh" events on POIs layer all 
        //     features have been destroyed by the Strategy.BBOX
        this.destroy();
        }
    }
    function onFeatureSelect(evt) {
        feature = evt.feature;
        var table = '<table>';
        for (var attr in feature.attributes.values) {
        table += '<tr><td>' + attr + '</td><td>' + feature.attributes.values[attr] + '</td></tr>';
        }
        table += '</table>';
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("featurePopup",
                             feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                             new OpenLayers.Size(100,100), table, null, true, onPopupClose);
        feature.popup = popup;
        popup.feature = feature;
        map.addPopup(popup, true);
    }
    function onFeatureUnselect(evt) {
        feature = evt.feature;
        if (feature.popup) {
        popup.feature = null;
        map.removePopup(feature.popup);
        feature.popup.destroy();
        feature.popup = null;
        }
    }
```

I want to highlight a city area using its latitude and longitude - how can I do this?

For Example: I want to highlight California on window load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use geometry.intersects():

```
function select() {
    var intersecting_feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-71.104939, 42.418935).transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857")));
    //vlayer.addFeatures([intersecting_feature]);
    var features = vlayer.features;
    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        var feature = features[i];
        console.log(feature.geometry);
        var intersection = feature.geometry.intersects(intersecting_feature.geometry);
        if (intersection) {
            console.log("ja");
            selectControl.select(feature);
        }

    }


}
```

see in action: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/h1mccjp6/

---

If just selecting by attribute is ok you can do the following:

You could use the method "getFeaturesByAttribute"

or iterate through all features:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < yourgeojsonlayer.features.length; i++) { 
    if(yourgeojsonlayer.features[i].attributes.searchedAttribute == 'searchedValue')
     { selectFeatureControl.select(yourgeojsonlayer.features[i]); break; } 
    }
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/f2omkcox/

Comment: Thanks - i want to select city using its latitude and longitude - is it possible?

Comment: do you know this example? http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/intersects.html

Comment: okay yes i know this

Comment: just added an example above that works

Comment: you are using coordinates to draw a Polygon type - but i want to highlight area of city without using these values -

Comment: sure. this is an example to show you how to use the intersects()-method. just adapt it to your vector layer

Comment: its like - where is california - highlight the area - where is New York - highlight New york

Comment: use only the function select(){} and replace var features = vlayer.features; with var features = shpLayer.features; and give it a try...

Comment: okay let me try this

Comment: no nothing highlighted :(

Comment: you could check if your select control is working, for example by selectControl.select(shpLayer.features[0]); and if yes, examine the coordinates of this feature. you declare EPSG as projection for the layer but reproject the geometries to EPSG3857...

Comment: Thomas - I have these coordinates for WEST BANK - {"type":"Feature","id":"PSE","properties":{"name":"West Bank"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[35.545665,32.393992],[35.545252,31.782505],[35.397561,31.489086],[34.927408,31.353435],[34.970507,31.616778],[35.225892,31.754341],[34.974641,31.866582],[35.18393,32.532511],[35.545665,32.393992]]]}}, - but following above example these couldn't work

Comment: i adapted my example to work with your Polygon. have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/6cdhfyuv/

Comment: can you please explain me what was the problem and how did you solve ?

Comment: The geojson you posted was not valid (perhaps copy/paste problem). Perhaps that was the Problem. Otherwise i just adapted the coordinates of the variable "intersecting_feature" and that was all. You can validate your geojson for example at http://geojsonlint.com/